# How do I correctly wire up a 2-pin panel LED to a 3 prong pinout?

Tags: motherboard, led

I've just finished building a system around the Asrock E3C236D2I C236 board and am having issues with the hard drive indicator LED and surprisingly all the other LEDs work fine. The pinout for the HDD indicator is quite unusual - usually these pinouts have a +/- or +/GND layout, however on this board there appears to be pins for all three, but only for this one LED.

When I connect the LED +/- it doesn't light up at all.
Connecting it to -/GND produces a solid light - no flickering on activity.
Breaking the cable out and connecting it to +/GND also produces a solid light with no flicker.

Also having the LED connected via the last two methods is intensely bright - literally blinding.

How should I correctly be connecting this?

[Pinout Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gDXc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at something wrong.

As seen here in the manual: http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/E3C236D2I.pdf

On page 6, the system panel header (Item 21) does not have a +,-,Gnd. In fact, it is only labeled HDLED.  Plugging the LED in one way will not work. Plugging it in the right way will work.

Comment: Page 6 makes things clearer - looks like there is a spare gnd pin, that I had the reset switch wired to; just moved everything along. However this didn't fix the led problem - turns out the m.2. riser board I was using had it's own pinouts for hd activity - this was somehow disabling the motherboard pinouts.